# Regex img tag with sizes and without

Tags: php, html, regex

I need to get the `<img>` tags from a page and transform them into `<amp-img>` tags. I'm using the following regex to get the tag `'/<img\s+src="([^"]+)"[^>]+>/i'` however, this regex takes only the images which are followed by the `src` attribute.

Is there a way to get also the images which have the `width` and `height` between `<img` and `src` for example: `<img width="300" height="244" src="img.jpg" />` ?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML.  Use a library designed for this.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  You already have the source code and are using php.  Just use a normal library designed for parsing HTML/XML to get data out of your source code.  There is no JS involved - of any kind.

Comment: Attributes can appear in any order so you can't use a regex to accurately pull them.

Comment: Aaaaaah time for [my favourite answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) again... :D

Comment: @CD001 I wish I could drop a pile of upvotes on your comment :)

Comment: Go as a professional instead :D https://github.com/Lullabot/amp-library